# Is there any state besides New Jersey that allows one to civilly remarry one's current spouse without divorcing?

Tags: marriage

A page from the New Jersey Health Department website [states](https://www.nj.gov/health/vital/registration-vital/marriage-licenses/#6) "For individuals who are currently married in New Jersey or who are married in another state or country, the option exists to reaffirm your relationship/vows by registering a remarriage." Is NJ alone in providing this option, or do any other US states or territories also allow this?

I am specifically interested in options for couples with foreign marriages to marry each other in the US without first divorcing.

Comment: The "divorce before remarry" requirement has one purpose: to avoid **bigamy** which is a huge big deal here, notably when Utah wanted statehood.  (see TV series *Big Love*). Bigamy requires 3 people.   I see no need for a divorce requirement if a registration does not create bigamy.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That makes perfect sense. Nonetheless, many state government websites state that registering a foreign marriage in the state is neither necessary nor possible. NJ is the only state I'm aware of that explicitly offers marriage registration for already-married couples.

Comment: Texas permits a couple to register their marriage as having occurred on a prior date. I knew at least two couples who did this, both registering the date as years before the date they went to the courthouse to file the registration. It is possible that Texas would accept such a registration for a marriage that did occur but according to a religion or jurisdiction that does not issue a marriage certificate. A Texas lawyer could provide further information.